# How do I manipulate variable length in google script editor?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script I am running as an example for my job.  It has to take a scanned value that is 12 Values in length, and compare the first 10 digits to another value that is acquired elsewhere.  I have all the rest of the script working, I just dont know how I can take a value like this(1234567890AB) and turn it into (1234567890) to make the comparison.

If that is not a possibility, is there a way I can compare (1234567890AB) to (1234567890) and only have it check the first 10 digits of each?  Below, I have an example of the scan code and the cell retrieval.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var userForm = ss.getSheetByName('T Line');
var partNumber = userForm.getRange(10,29).getValue();
var quantity = userForm.getRange(10, 06).getValue();
var check = 0;
var orderManifest = ss.getSheetByName('Order Manifest');

do {
while (check != quantity){
  var check = check + 1;
  }
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var scannedData = ui.prompt("Scan Part Number QR Code");
  var text = scannedData.getResponseText();
  var btn = ui.ButtonSet.OK;
  if(text == partNumber){
    Logger.log(text);
    ui.alert("QR Code matches part number.",btn);
  }
  if(text != partNumber){
    Logger.log(text);
    ui.alert("QR Code does NOT match",btn);
    var check = check - 1;
    var question = Browser.msgBox("Please verify the correct part number is selected and try again.", Browser.Buttons.OK);
  }  
}
I
```

honestly dont know where to begin with this.  I have tried searching for this for a few hours, and had no success finding a solution.  I assume its probably a pretty basic solution.  Ive just never had any formal training when it comes to coding, I have had to teach myself over the course of a month or two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) to get the first 10 digits:

```js
/*<ignore>*/console.config({maximize:true,timeStamps:false,autoScroll:false});/*</ignore>*/ 
const s1 = "1234567890AB";
const s2 = "1234567890";
console.info(String(s1).slice(0,10) === String(s2))
```

```html
<!-- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375985/ -->    <script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do that is by using `indexOf()`
[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Using this way you are not limited to 10 / 12 chars schema.

```
var textA = '123457890';
var textB = '1234567890AB';

if ( textB.indexOf(textA) ==  0 ) Logger.log( 'textB "begins" with textA');
if ( textB.indexOf(textA) == -1 ) Logger.log( 'textB is not into textA');
```